# Is there a way to create a directory by cutting a tgz file name in sections?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ubuntu

So I got multiple .tgz files listed here :

```
Huistaak1-HelloWorld_Jan.Janssens.s.ua_poging_2019-11-09.tgz
Huistaak1-HelloWorld_Jolien.Peters.s.ua_poging_2019-11-11.tgz
Huistaak1-HelloWorld_Jonas.De.Preter.s.ua_poging_2019-11-12.tgz
Huistaak1-HelloWorld_Len.Feremans.s.ua_poging_2019-11-10.tgz
Huistaak1-HelloWorld_Peter.Hofkens.s.ua_poging_2019-11-11.tgz
Huistaak1-HelloWorld_Sarah.Van.Hoof.s.ua_poging_2019-11-11.tgz
```

So I need to filter out the names from these files and save them into a variable so that I can use that variable to create a directory
Note: I cannot simply use  -> mkdir Janssens.Jan

For example the first file has the name - Jan.Janssens
With that name I would need to create a directory called - Janssens.Jan
In total I should have 6 directories like this

```
Janssens.Jan
Peters.Jolien
De.Preter.Jonas
Feremans.Len
Hofkens.Peter
Van.Hoof.Sarah
```

Is there a way that I can filter out the name from every file without having to go through each of them ?

Something like for filename in *.tgz; do ...

Comment: There are many ways to achieve that - what have you tried?

Comment: I didn't try much because I don't really know how.
I tried this 
```
name1=$(echo Huistaak1-HelloWorld_Jan.Janssens.s.ua_poging_2019-11-09.tgz | cut -f2 -d '_')
mkdir -p "$name1"
```
but then I would have to do it for every single tgz file and I don't get the result I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bash` and a `regex`. I assume that there is always `.s` after the names.

```
for i in *.tgz; do
  [[ $i =~ ([^_.]+)\.([^_]+)\.s ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.${BASH_REMATCH[1]}";
done
```

If string `$i` matches regex `[^_.]+\.[^_]+\.s` (I remove all round brackets) then print element 2 (`${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`) from array `BASH_REMATCH` followed by a `.` and element 1 (`${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`) from array `BASH_REMATCH`. Element 1 contains matching part from regex between first round brackets `[^_.]+` and element 2 contains matching part between second round brackets `[^_]+`. `\.` represents a `.` and not a special character of a regex.

Output:

```
Janssens.Jan
Peters.Jolien
De.Preter.Jonas
Feremans.Len
Hofkens.Peter
Van.Hoof.Sarah
```

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Can you explain what this does ? [[ $i =~ ([^_.]+)\.([^_]+)\.s ]]

I know it's regex but I don't understand how you got it

Comment: @FieldyScop: I've updated my answer. I hope it became more understandable.